# How to open Firefox Developer Edition with Webpack serve and DevServer --open option?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, firefox-developer-edition, webpack-serve

How to open **Firefox Developer Edition** with `webpack serve` using [`devServer.open` config option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropen)?

I've tried to use these configuration values on Windows: *'Mozilla', 'mozilla', 'Firefox', 'firefox', 'Firefox Developer Edition'*

```js
devServer: {
  open: 'mozilla',
},
```

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. Am looking to see which one casts more votes, to see what works for the people. Solution may vary i.e. per OS version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, found a workaround.

You need to set Firefox Developer Edition as a default browser in order for it to work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/open#target

> **target**
>
> Type: *string*
>
> The thing you want to open. Can be a URL, file, or executable.
>
> Opens in the default app for the file type. For example, URLs opens in
> your **default browser.**

Then add **target** property to your **webpack.config.js** like this

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    open: {
        target: 'index.html'
    }
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu so I'm not sure if it will work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the full path to the browser you want to use. Note that this will only work on one machine, so do not use it in shared projects, or use an environment variable. This config worked for me:

```
devServer: {
    open: 'C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**For macOS user**

In order to open ***Firefox Developer Edition*** with `webpack serve` using `devServer.open` option, you can write the name of the app like this:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    open: "Firefox Developer Edition",
    port: 9001,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true,
    },
  }
```

As for the other browsers, you need to write the exact name you see in your Applications folder. Like when you open your browser with your terminal app.

---

1. This question gave me the idea [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/1090708/how-to-open-mozilla-developer-edition-from-terminal)
2. Tested on macOS Big Sur
3. Webpack v5.36.2
4. Webpack-CLI v4.7.0
5. webpack DevServer v3.11.2